# apktool decode error on 32-bit Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, apk

When I run `apktool` on Ubuntu 12.04 LTE(32), something is wrong. But when I run it on Ubuntu 12.04 LTE(64), everything is ok.

```
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.directory.DirectoryException: java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.hasResources(ApkDecoder.java:247)
    at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:91)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:169)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:85)
Caused by: brut.directory.DirectoryException: java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    at brut.directory.ZipRODirectory.<init>(ZipRODirectory.java:54)
    at brut.directory.ZipRODirectory.<init>(ZipRODirectory.java:37)
    at brut.androlib.res.util.ExtFile.getDirectory(ExtFile.java:55)
    at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.hasResources(ApkDecoder.java:245)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory32(ZipFile.java:717)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:672)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:406)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:206)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:182)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:143)
    at brut.directory.ZipExtFile.<init>(ZipExtFile.java:28)
    at brut.directory.ZipRODirectory.<init>(ZipRODirectory.java:52)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: If this is the exact same file, try and see whether there is any corruption (for instance, check that the output of `sha1sum` is the same on both systems)

Comment: thank you.just like what you have said.